# Second Event Hijacks First Handler

Tags: c#, async-await, event-handling, blazor

I have a Blazor component with two buttons that execute the same underlying service class async method. As that method operates, it iterates on some data for enrichment and emits an event per iteration that the component handles to update a progress bar per button.

I've set the service event handlers up as local functions within the `@click` event method. This local function handles the target element's counters for progress and the JS interop to update the UI. This all works as expected when clicked individually and allowed to complete before clicking the other button. **The problem is that if both buttons are clicked fast enough together, whereby the first operation is still processing, the second event handler hijacks the first and all callbacks flow to it**. The first progress bar idles and the second one goes over 100%.

**Component.razor**

```
@inject IFooService FooService

<a class="btn btn-light p-1 @(isExcelProcessing ? "disabled" : null) " role="button" @onclick="ExportExcel">
            <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o text-dark fa-2x"></i><br>
            <span class="small text-nowrap">
                Summary Excel
                @if (isExcelProcessing)
                {
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 15px">
                        <div id="excelProgressBar" ></div>
                    </div>
                }
            </span>
        </a>

<a class="btn btn-light @(isTextProcessing ? "disabled" : null) " role="button" @onclick="ExportText">
            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-file-text-o text-dark"></i><br />
            <span class="small text-nowrap">
                Instruction Text
                @if (isTextProcessing)
                {
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 15px">
                        <div id="textProgressBar" ></div>
                    </div>
                }
            </span>
        </a>

@code {

    private bool isExcelProcessing = false;
    private bool isTextProcessing = false;

    private async Task ExportExcel()
    {
        isExcelProcessing = true;
        var excelIssuesCounter = 0;
        var excelProcessingComplete = 0m;

        var itemsToEnrichCount = (await FooService.GetItemsToEnrich()).ToArray();

        void OnFetched(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {            
            excelIssuesCounter++;
            excelProcessingComplete = (Convert.ToDecimal(excelIssuesCounter) / itemsToEnrichCount) * 100;
            JS.InvokeVoidAsync("updateProgress",
                "excelProgressBar",
                excelProcessingComplete);
        }
        
        FooService.OnFetched += OnFetched;

        // this method has the iterations that call back to the defined event handler
        var fooData = await FooService.GetDataAsync("excel");

        //  do other stuff like building a model, 
        //  render a template from razor engine
        //  download the file        

        isExcelProcessing = false;
        FooService.OnFetched -= OnIssueFetched;
    }

    private async Task ExportText()
    {
        isTextProcessing = true;
        var textIssuesCounter = 0;
        var textProcessingComplete = 0m;

        var itemsToEnrichCount = (await FooService.GetItemsToEnrich()).ToArray();

        void OnFetched(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {            
            textIssuesCounter++;
            textProcessingComplete = (Convert.ToDecimal(textIssuesCounter) / itemsToEnrichCount) * 100;
            JS.InvokeVoidAsync("updateProgress",
                "textProgressBar",
                textProcessingComplete);
        }
        
        FooService.OnFetched += OnFetched;

        // this method has the iterations that call back to the defined event handler
        var fooData = await FooService.GetDataAsync("text");

        //  do other stuff like building a model, 
        //  render a template from razor engine
        //  download the file        

        isTextProcessing = false;
        FooService.OnFetched -= OnFetched;
    }
}
```

**FooService.cs**

```
public event EventHandler OnFetched;

public async Task<FooData> GetDataAsync()
{
    // not material to the problem. just here for example
    var dataToEnrich = GetRawData();
    var result = new FooData();    

    foreach(var itemToEnrich in dataToEnrich)
    {
        var enrichedFoo = await EnrichAsync(itemToEnrich);
        result.EnrichedItems.Add(enrichedFoo);

        // this is the material operation that doesn't always go to the desired handler
        OnFetched?.Invoke(this, null);
    }  

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. Based on your description it sounds like multicasting isn't working. What happens if you inject a service factory instead? `@inject Func<IFooService> FooServiceFactory` you will need to register the service factory.

Comment: Just as a Diagnostic, could you rename those 2 methods to OnFetched1() and OnFetched2() ? And maybe pull them out of the parent methods?   The C# here is transpiled, I wonder if something odd could be going on there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, the name's don't affect any change. Neither does the parent scope. Even if scoped at a higher level than a local function, the same behavior is observed.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Yes, multi-casting is not doing what it seems like it should be doing. Curious where I'd go with a factory here. Are you suggesting I have a different service class instance per event? That would certainly eliminate a multi-cast scenario as each event would be emitted from their own source object. But that's a load of snakes I don't really want to sub for this one rat.

Comment: Yeah, I was suggesting you use multiple service instances but only for diagnostic purposes

Comment: What's the scope of `FooService`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, `FooService` I've tried Scoped and Transient scoping when adding it to the Services collection.

Comment: @ajamrozek.  Thanks.  I've re-written you code into a simpler version to try and track the object instances and understand the behaviour.  I'm totally confused at the moment, as there seems to be different behaviour patterns depending on when you click the second button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your basic approach here is flawed.  Let me explain:

- Click A
- Hook up Handler A to Event
- Call GetDataAsync(A)
- Some loops happen, but are not complete
- Click B
- Hook up Handler B to Event
- Call GetDataAsync(B)
- GetDataAsync(B) loops and fires Event
- Both Handler A and Handler B fires  (I don't think you intend that!)
  ....

You are using the same Event Handler for both calls to `GetDataAsync`.  When both `GetDataAsync` methods are running each handler is getting the events from both.

The sequencing of events gets pretty confusing based on the timing of the second click.  Async behaviour is not always an exact science and you may be in edge territory.  I think this is caused by the way the Thread Task Scheduler prioritises it's tasks (but that's no more than an educated guess and I may be totally wrong!).  I won't go as far as saying there's a bug, but...  it needs more investigation.

##### Update

Here's a simplified version of your code that uses callbacks for isolation:

```
public class MyService
{
    public async Task<SomeData> GetDataAsync(Action<SomeData> callback)
    {
        var result = new SomeData();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            item.Value = $"updated at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";

            callback.Invoke(result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private List<SomeData> data => new List<SomeData> {
       new SomeData { Key = "France" },
       new SomeData { Key = "Portugal" },
       new SomeData { Key = "Spain" },
   };
}

public class SomeData
{
    public string Key { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public string Value { get; set; } = String.Empty ;
}
```

Demo Page:

```
@page "/"
@inject MyService myService

<div class="p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=FirstClicked>First</button>
    <div class="p-2">
        Counter = @firstCounter;
    </div>
</div>
<div class="p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-info" @onclick=SecondClicked>First</button>
    <div class="p-2">
        Counter = @secondCounter;
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    int firstCounter = 0;
    int secondCounter = 0;

    private async void FirstClicked()
    {
        firstCounter = 0;
        void firstHandler(SomeData data)
        {
            firstCounter++;
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
        var ret = await this.myService.GetDataAsync(firstHandler);
    }


    private async void SecondClicked()
    {
        secondCounter = 0;
        var ret = await this.myService.GetDataAsync((data) =>
          {
              secondCounter++;
              this.StateHasChanged();
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, good catch. FooService is a Singleton, at least in this page. Still not obvious why _"The first progress bar idles"_ but probably because InvokeVoidAsync is not awaited.

Comment: I think you're on to something with the discrete callbacks. I'll give that a go. This may just be semantics but I'm deliberately avoiding `StateHasChanged()` and depending on JS interop to adjust DOM elements to avoid re-rendering more content than needed.

Comment: NP.  But don't get hung up on minimizing re-rendering.  You can easily end up jumping through hoops backwards.  Manipulating elements directly thro JS  can lead to mismatches between the actual DOM and the Render's DOM and unexpected consequences.   We see many questions on SO about it.

Comment: Initially I tried brute-force two-way binding that progressBar value to a component C# value and calling `StateHasChanged()` on sub-event (loop-iteration). I'd love to make that work opposed to the JS interop and jQuery DOM dance. Without that, however, changes weren't reflected in the DOM until the super-event (onclick) completed. Perhaps something else was in my way there, but that was before I even introduced the second button.

Comment: I'll add the progress bar into my answer and post what I get a little later.  It should work!

Comment: @ajamrozek - when your first (non JS) approach didin't work then EnrichAsync() isn't really async.

Comment: Passing the `Action` to the method instead of a class member `EventHandler` did the trick.